# Compiling a static pkg-config binary

Tags: c++, gcc, static, libtool, pkg-config

I'm trying to build a static pkg-config binary, using:

```
LDFLAGS='-static' ./configure --disable-shared
```

However, the produced binary is dynamically linked. I even tried fiddling with the Makefile, using:

```
CC = gcc -static
```

and

```
CCLD = gcc -static
```

but still no go, always shared, not static. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
LDFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc" LIBS="-lpthread" CFLAGS="-Wl,-static" ./configure
```